# Trigger after insert doesn't fire for each row

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Hey i have a trigger that fires after update that's defined as following:

```
CREATE DEFINER =  `root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `logs_m` AFTER UPDATE ON  
`logs_month` FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN IF NEW.status =1 THEN INSERT INTO logs_payments( direction, 
TYPE , amount, agent_id, invoice_number ) 
VALUES ( 0, 3, NEW.reward_minutes, NEW.agent_id, NULL ) ,
 ( 0, 5, NEW.credit, NEW.agent_id, NULL ) ;

END IF ;
END
```

Now on `logs_payments` i have a trigger on after insert which is defined like this :

```
CREATE DEFINER =  `root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `payments_invoice` BEFORE INSERT ON 
 `logs_payments` 
FOR EACH
ROW BEGIN 
IF NEW.direction =0
THEN 
SET NEW.invoice_number = ( SELECT MAX( IFNULL( invoice_number, 100000000 ) ) +1
FROM logs_payments l
WHERE l.direction =0 ) ;

END IF ;

IF NEW.direction =1 THEN SET NEW.invoice_number = 
( SELECT MAX( IFNULL( invoice_number, 200000000 ) ) +1
FROM logs_payments l
WHERE l.direction =1 ) ;

END IF ;

END
```

Now the the first inserted row `invoice_number` gets null and the 2nd gets the right value.

Any idea why that should happen?

Comment: Why on Earth aren't you using [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-auto-increment.html)?

Comment: Because that table has other values as well and i already have an auto_incremented column. and not all columns should have the value.

Comment: So `invoice_number` is not the PK in `logs_payments` but it is designed to be both unique and non-dependent on the PK?  Sounds like you could do with normalising your schema.

Comment: Ever got management change their minds? :) Changing the schema would be too costly, but thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, the triggers where fine I had a problem in my query, since I didn't have value on first I set :

```
SELECT MAX( IFNULL( invoice_number, 100000000 ) ) +1
```

Which was wrong it should be

```
select ifnull(max(invoice_number),100000000)+1
```

And now it works fine.